# How to write a custom hook which has multiple async functions inside it so that I can separate logic on the custom hook?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, mern

The code for the custom hook, useCast is as follows:

```
const useCart = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  const toast = useToast();

  const addToCart = async (categoryId, quantity) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const res = await ax.post("/cart", { category: categoryId, quantity });
      setCart(res.data?.categories);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      setError(err.response?.data);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  const getCartList = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const res = await ax.get("/cart/");
      setCart(res.data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      setError(err.response?.data);
    }
    setLoading(false);
    return cart;
  };

  const emptyCartState = () => {
    setCart([]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error)
      toast({
        title: error,
        status: "error",
        isClosable: true,
      });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [error]);

  return {
    addToCart,
    cart,
    useCartLoading: loading,
    useCartError: error,
    getCartList,
    emptyCartState,
  };
};

export default useCart;
```

And it is being called like this:

```
const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { cartDispatch } = useContext(CartContext);

  const { cart, getCartList, useCartLoading } = useCart();

  // const viewCartList = async () => {
  //   try {
  //     const res = await ax.get("/cart/");
  //     return res.data;
  //   } catch (error) {
  //     console.log(error.response?.data);
  //   }
  // };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      const updateCart = async () => {
        const updatedCart = await getCartList();
        console.log(updatedCart);
        // console.log(useCartLoading);
        cartDispatch({ type: "UPDATE_CART", payload: updatedCart });
      };
      updateCart();
    } else {
      cartDispatch({ type: "UPDATE_CART", payload: [] });
    }
  }, [user]);
```

Can anyone please help me out with this? Whenever I use custom hook, it does not work. The commented out ViewCartList works though, so I'm guessing it's the custom hook which has not been implemented correctly. The custom hook returns old data, and does not return the updated data on first call. Like it returns updated data on second call for same request.
How do you implement custom hooks? What I want to achieve is that, I want to separate the logic on the custom hook, and based on what the custom hook returns, I want to update my context values on the page. The functions inside the hook has to be async.

Comment: will be helpful if you can share an example link for the same

Comment: You should handle the logic that you are currently handling in the `useCart` inside the `CartContext` since you are using it as a dispatcher and state manager.